# How to specify file path with find when searching for files with -regex

Tags: find

I want to search a directory for some files using `find` and a regular expression.

If I do

```
cd dir
find -E . -type f -regex '^\..*[^~]'
```

I get a list of files in the directory that match the the regular expression.

However, if I do

```
find -E ~/dir -type f -regex '^\..*[^~]'
```

i.e.

```
find -E /home/adam/dir -type f -regex '^\..*[^~]'
```

I get no output. How do I specify the directory to be searched by `find` when using a regular expression?

This is BSD `find`, as I am on a Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument to `-regex` has to match the whole path that is found. A command like `find .` finds paths like `./dir/subdir/somefile`, while a command like `find ~/dir` finds paths like `/home/adam/dir/subdir/somefile`. So your regexp has to match the 
`/home/adam` part at the beginning.

The command `find -E . -type f -regex '^\..*[^~]'` finds files whose name doesn't contain a newline and doesn't end with `~`. The `.` at the beginning always matches since the path begins with `./`.

If you were looking for dot files, you'd need to allow for a directory prefix. The following command shows dot files whose name doesn't end in `~`:

```
find -E /whatever -regex '(\n|.)*/\.[^/]*[^~]'
```

But this is simpler to express with `-name`:

```
find /whatever -name '.*[!~]'
```

Comment: I was asked to change `~/dir` in my question to `$HOME/dir`, so you might want to update your answer accordingly. At any rate, thanks for the help!

Comment: @AdamLiter I don't see the point of using `$HOME` instead of `~`. At least [quote it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Comment: I was asked to change my question so that it was more transparent to new users (though the comments have now been deleted). As I'm not really a regular on this site at all, I just went along with the suggestion. And I didn't want anyone to be confused that you have `find ~/dir` in your answer rather than `find $HOME/dir`, as is now in my question. I do agree that there doesn't seem to be much of a point in using `$HOME` instead of `~`. All that being said, maybe these comments are now enough so that users won't be confused by the discrepancy, and you can leave your answer as is. Thanks again!